# Does $location service override Spring Security login success url?

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

I have the following Security Config with Spring 3.2

```
.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome", false)
            .failureUrl("/notexistpage")
```

I got the conclusion that defaultSuccessUrl() and failureUrl() was performed, related page loaded but was ignored by Angularjs frontend with ng-route/$location.

I have a Single Page Application on index.html with has the following ng-view block, it is basically a bootstrap Nav panel with a login button:

```
<li class="nav-item" ng-show="!authenticated">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="login-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="login" aria-expanded="true" href="#!/login">Login</a>
                    </li>

<div ng-view class="container"></div>
```

A login page would be displayed on ng-view block, and I have ng-click() function which submit the form to javascript function following:

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'perform_login',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
                transformRequest: function(obj) {
                    var str = [];
                    for(var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                },               
                data: credentials
            }).then(function (response) {
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;                
                callback && callback();
            }, function (response) {
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;                
                callback && callback();
            });
```

The page would have different behaviour depending on success/failed login, but nonetheless return a status code of 200/302/304, which javascript considered as success. Also the login form would remain in the  block, neglecting Java Success Handler. The page did requested the html defined in defaultSuccessUrl(), but it was not shown on the page.

I could only hard code $location.path("/") after login success ( first callback of javascript ), and force user to login before accessing any page.

Comment: were you able to fix this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use Spring Securitys `defaultSuccessUrl` here.
The control of the webflow should be on the client. Take a look at the [official example](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/), they're doing the same.

```
angular.module('hello', [ 'ngRoute' ]) // ... omitted code
.controller('navigation',

  function($rootScope, $http, $location) {

  var self = this

  var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

    var headers = credentials ? {authorization : "Basic "
        + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
    } : {};

    $http.get('user', {headers : headers}).then(function(response) {
      if (response.data.name) {
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
      } else {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
      }
      callback && callback();
    }, function() {
      $rootScope.authenticated = false;
      callback && callback();
    });

  }

  authenticate();
  self.credentials = {};
  self.login = function() {
      authenticate(self.credentials, function() {
        if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
          $location.path("/");
          self.error = false;
        } else {
          $location.path("/login");
          self.error = true;
        }
      });
  };
});
```